# How to decrypt text in PHP encypted with Taifun AES-Extention?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, app-inventor

I'm trying to use an `appinventor` extension that encrypts a text with "`AES 128, CBC, and PKCS5 padding`". I've tried a lot but I can't decrypt the text on my PHP(7.2.9) Server.

On [this site](https://puravidaapps.com/aes.php) he describes what [library](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) he used, but I can't use it in php.

The [openssl_decript](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) would decript `AES-128-CBC` but it can't decrypt a massage that the extension encrypted. The extension encrypts with a password and a salt which is generated from the password within the app.

My PHP-Server code:

```
(index.php)
<?php
$password = $_POST["pw"];
$salt = $_POST["salt"];
$iv_mac_text = $_POST["text"];

$method = "AES-128-CBC";
$keyLength = 16;
$iterations = 10000;

echo "Iv, mac and text:$iv_mac_text \n --------------- \n";
echo "Salt:$salt \n --------------- \n";
echo "Password:$password \n --------------- \n";

$saltdecoded = base64_decode($salt);

$generated_key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $saltdecoded, $keyLength, $iterations, 'sha1');

$keyencoded = base64_encode($generated_key);
echo "confidentialityKey:$keyencoded \n --------------- \n";

$exploded = explode(":", $iv_mac_text);
$iv = base64_decode($exploded[0]);
$mac = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
$encryptedtext = base64_decode($exploded[2]);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($exploded[2], $method, $keyencoded,  OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

$textlength = strlen($decrypted);
echo "Decrypted text ($textlength chars): $decrypted \n --------------- \n";
?>
```

The app that I've created to test it:

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRr9D.png)
[blockeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA83R.png)

You can download the [apk](https://httpsphp.at/dateiaustausch/down.php?rq=APK-AES).
For the Server-address type that in the first textbox(without the space):
 
(example fill in your own server adress)
http ://your.domain/your/directory/index.php

Comment: You should post an example key, IV, and ciphertext.

Comment: Password:TestPHP
salt:qkKGerLnMCQ5aZPlO f6mTlhZVQ/lB78bApkwM7EywIzfxOCxFpTEF0Wbj8vRZL9Q8DNaRrUIjqptM51Nd6wORvX4OhraO9 iSmb3o97TiEk9UyISME4JGP9iP2PZgla9gjOCq6uIe1OuEaJeP8c8VG/vqrpk vRKtoUN7645T4=
ivmactext:tVCIyCqaF8roVO5pimXDDg==:qM4GI5sgi3JQnkMwVMz4BPX83udlIpMPAYTEnQfnkHA=:dTHIvS6O6G8ngUnMvrFmWQ==
Massage was: TextToEncrypt

Comment: Just E-mailed the creator of the library and he said that it can't be decrypted with PHP! Thanks for the help anyways!!

Comment: Sounds like a giant cop-out to me. Please put your example data in the question body and format it so that it's actually usable. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a PHP Library to decrypt Taifuns and Tiziano1960 (Both work because they are based on the same JAVA Library). You find all informations [here](http://projects.technerd.at/aeslib/).

Comment: Consider editing your answer and add more details about this solution.

Comment: Well it took me almost 2 jears to finish it becuse i had to lern java and php.. I will add mor informations but for now i have enough for the moment.. (Don't take it in any way offensive you can visit my webside and download the extention best regards ;))

Comment: I just have been reviewing queues. Link can always disappear, post remains on SO. So moderators encourage users to be more specific while writing answers (not only posting links).